# How to do client side paging on a DevExpress GridView using a List DataSoure dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, paging, aspxgridview

Using DevExpress v11.1 I've implemented a List based datasource bound to the gridview dynamically in code behind. Attached to this I use the client side `PerformCallback` to populate the grid with data based on user selections. This all works fine.

However, when paging is enabled, the grid will not refresh unless it is rebound to the datasource, which is the expected behavior. If I change the page and then manual force the grid to rebind, it displays the correct page.

I can't find anything in the documentation about which method to implement to fire the page selection client side. This will allow me to fire the `PerformCallback` again once the page has been selected.

Any idea/suggestions at what I need to be looking at to achieve this?

Comment: Will this work for you:  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GotoPagetopic

Comment: @Filip Almost. I need to catch the event GotoPage Fires. The actual pager works, the grid itself is not rebound after firing however.

Comment: I suppose you could use this event:  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_PageIndexChangedtopic  But, if you bind grid in code behind you should always bind it in Init event handler. Look here for explanation: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18282.aspx  Regardless of that article, you will save yourself a lot of time if you use Init for grid binding. Of course, you can still rebind it in PerformCallback when necessary.

Comment: @Filip The grid doesn't bind until a selection is actually made. Not sure if init is the right place for it. But will read and follow up. Also the PageIndexEvent is a server side event, not a client side event.

Comment: I thought you wanted to catch it on server side. Anyway, you should always bind grid in Init handler and rebind it in PerformCallback when necessary. I don't know how complicated your grid is, but different approach can become very messy.

Comment: @Filip I have solved it in the meantime. The grid loads empty, and only ever binds on the `PerformCallback`. Any time earlier would be a wasted SQL query. However, the trick was to use the client-side `EndCallback` and just pass a global parameter with regards to whether it is being loaded for the first time, or being refreshed by a grid action internally.